# Python string format "%4d"%

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have this code:

```
print("%4d"%word, end="")
```

Right now it's hard-coded to 4 letters words (The GUI is in the terminal)

I would like, if possible, for it to be dynamic after the biggest word chosen, is that possible and if so how?

Comment: `"%*d" % (n, word)` will format it to a width of `n`.

Comment: @Ryan Better make it an answer,

Comment: Very useful article about text formatting https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 1):

Using the new python formatting you could do it as follows:

```
print "{{0}:.{1}}".format(word, n)
```